# redefining already defined variables in integration

Tags: calculus

I have a question about redefining variables. In some proofs a variable  is defined and later it is defined otherwise. This doesn't make sense to me.

Consider the following proof for example:
http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780538497909-stewart-calculus-early-transcendentals-7th-edition/415/exercises/90/#

First the variable u is substituted for pi-x, implying x=pi-u . Later in the proof x is integrated as u, implying u=x. To me this seems contradictory, but it surely isn't. What is a systematic way to determine whether this redefining is allowed? Why is this not contradictory?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "Later in the proof x is integrated as u, implying u=x."? Where exactly in the proof?

Comment: The integral of f(sin(u)) is replaced with the integral of f(sin(x)) so as to complete the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the rest of the proof, but I can guess what the proof does. Remember that the variable of integration is just a dummy variable placeholder, so:
$$
\int g(x) \, dx = \int g(u) \, du = \int g(t) \, dt = \int g(a) \, da = \int g(b) \, db = \cdots
$$
So:
$$
\mathbf{I} = \int_0^\pi (\pi - u) f(\sin u) \, du = \int_0^\pi (\pi - x) f(\sin x) \, dx = \int_0^\pi \pi f(\sin x)\, dx - \mathbf{I}
$$
implying that:
$$
\mathbf I = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\, dx
$$

Comment: This is exactly what i still dont get. why can you change u to x directly while u was substituted for pi-x? To me it seems as if you commit to u=pi-x and then just drop that definition out of nowhere.

Comment: Here's an analogy. Suppose that $F(x) = 3x$ so that $F(a) = 3a$ and $F(b) = 3b$ and so on. Now consider the substitution $u = x + 1$ so that $x = u - 1$. Then we have $F(u - 1) = 3(u - 1)$. But since $u$ is just a dummy variable, we know that $F(c - 1) = 3(c - 1)$ and $F(d - 1) = 3(d - 1)$ and $F(x - 1) = 3(x - 1)$. All that I did was replace $x$ with $x - 1$. We're using the same principle here with the integrals.

Comment: I see how this would work for definite integrals now because you integrate the dummy variable out, but this wouldn't work for indefinite integrals right? Because if you first make a substitution u=x+1  and then substitute u=x your end answer is different(=wrong)?